# Bootstrap collapsable doesn't work

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm new in Bootstrap and Angular. I want to make a collapsable list group, but it does not collapse. Should I include something more? I'm using Angular4 & Bootsrap 4.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i runed your code snippet and the collapse works.

Comment: You need popper.js

Comment: popper.js installed

Answer (score 0):

i runed your code snippet and the collapse works. Verify your Network tab on "developer tools" `F12`, check if all the requests ends successfully, because you're requesting bootstrap from a link, and if the request be to slow, it can crash. Also verify your browser version for support bootstrap 4

Comment: Checked the network tab, I only have 304 and 200 statuses. I think I missed something during the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below was duplicated into my components, but it needs only in index.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```